# Linking two django fields in two different models

Tags: python, django

I am going slightly crazy as I am sure this is a super simple question. I have two models in django:

```
class Play(models.Model):
    gid = models.IntegerField()
    pid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    off = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    deff = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class FGXP(models.Model):
    pid = models.IntegerField()
    fgxp = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    fkicker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is a football database and when there is a Play that scores there is another table where additional data about the extra point is held: FGXP. So in Play pid is the primary_key. In FGXP there is a link between pid and the pid in play. In my Django model should I link them? I will end up needing to join the data when I do a query.

Thanks - an apologies if a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a Foreign Key from `FGXP` to `Play` like so

```
class FGXP(models.Model:
   play = models.ForeignKey(Play, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
   fgxp = models.CharField(...)
   ...
```

which would make `FGXP` exist on a `Play` instance as the attribute `fgxp_set`

I think a FK would work here because there are potentially more than one extra point plays, especially when a penalty is called.

Comment: You should called it `play` instead of `pid` now that it is a `ForeignKey` as django will automatically append `_id` to `ForeignKey`s